# Cannot pass large json string to another Page with asp.net c# and knockoutjs

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I got a problem while working with knockoutJs and asp.net c#.
When I passed a json string from page to another popup page using jquery ajax and knockoutJs for printing.
The problem occur:

When the Json string is small. It works fine, the popup page shows string data in table.

However, when the json string is large. It doesn't work anymore. The error occurs with message:

"Uncaught Sys.ArgumentException: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data"

Here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'InProgressBrief.aspx/PrintReport',
            data: ko.toJSON({ reportData: ko.toJSON(InProgressBriefs.Briefs) }),
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                window.open("PrintInProgressBrief.aspx?month=" + InProgressBriefs.Month() + "&year=" + InProgressBriefs.Year(), "", "status=0,toolbar=0,width=1000,height=900");
            }
        })
```

Here is my webMethod

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void PrintReport(string reportData)
    {
        PSCDialog.DataShare = reportData;
    }
```

The popup page recieves the Json tring:

```
   if (PSCDialog.DataShare != null)
       return PSCDialog.DataShare as string;
```

In the popup page UI, I set the knockoutjs variable, my UI javascript code is something like follow:

```
var InProgressBriefs = {
        Briefs: ""
;
$(function(){
   InProgressBriefs.Briefs = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize('<%=ReportJSONData%>');  
   ko.applyBindings(InProgressBriefs, $('#mainDivPrint')[0]);
})
```

Would anyone please tell me what is the problem here? I will appreciate your help alot.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's a little suspicious is the line

```
data: ko.toJSON({ reportData: ko.toJSON(InProgressBriefs.Briefs) }),
```

When that's deserialized, you wind up with `reportData` being a JSON-encoded *string* rather than a native *object*. I doubt that's what you want. More likely what you need is

```
data: ko.toJSON({ reportData: ko.toJS(InProgressBriefs.Briefs) }),
```

which serializes only once.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I see your point. In this case, I want to send only the json string to the popup page instead of the object. According to the KnockoutJS documentation writes that: "ko.toJSON — this produces a JSON string representing your view model’s data. Internally, it simply calls ko.toJS on your view model, and then uses the browser’s native JSON serializer on the result" So I think ko.toJSON is enough!